# Laravel / MySql Unique String Based On Id?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following migration to create my MySQL database table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_auth_keys', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('key', 800);
        $table->string('first_name', 80);
        $table->string('last_name', 80);
        $table->timestamps();

        // link project id with real project id
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
    });
}
```

Now what I want ot accomplish is make 'key' "unique"... However I know that I can do that by simply changing

```
$table->string('key', 800)->unique();
```

But I don't want to make it unique for the whole table I want to make it unique based on project_id.

For example a entry with project_id of 1 and a entry with project_id of 2 can have the same key, however there cannot be 2 same keys in the same project_id.

Is this something I can do within MySQL or will I have to make this as a rule within my controller? I can do it in my controller not a problem, but I would rather do it in my database if possible.

**EDIT**

Tried adding

```
$table->primary(array('project_id', 'key'));
```

Added it right below $table->primary(array('project_id', 'key'));

However after doing this I am getting a error when trying to run the migration.

[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to make a composite key involving both the project_id and the key except as a foreign key and not a primary key.

Comment: why don't you create 2 tables. One for the project id and then one for the key that is associated to the primary key? (i'm not sure why you would want to do this at all so I'm not sure how i would write this exactly... but it is an idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$table->primary(array('project_id', 'key'));
```

You can find the same in the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-indexes).

Solution 1: Since you already have a increment column defined, it is taking the same as a default primary key.

To use a composite primary key, you can either remove that column or calculate that column differently, otherwise it would throw you a duplicate primary key exception.

Also, the limitation of the length of primary key is "767" and hence you should reduce your key length to lower than that if possible.

I just tried the following and it works:

```
Schema::create('test', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('key', 100); // make sure the key length is within sql standards(767), "800" is not acceptable for primary key
$table->string('first_name', 80);
$table->string('last_name', 80);
$table->timestamps();
// Add primary
$table->primary( array( 'key', 'project_id' ) );
});
```

Solution 2: You can just perform the validation in controller, that gives you more flexibility I believe and have the same structure, with just id as primary key. However, I am not very confident about performance. You will have to check on that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think so I am trying to make 'key' unique but only unique with same 'project_id' so if 'project_id' is different they 'key' can be different.

Comment: Actually after you edited that let me try that and see if that works.

Comment: Should work according to me. This is composite primary key, combination should be unique..

Comment: When I add this to my migration and I try to migrate I get a error thrown. Here is the error ( http://pasteboard.co/5GuoxK2.jpg ) and here is what I changed my migration too ( http://pastebin.com/0HqvFJia )

Comment: Hmm, That makes since I need to make the key 800 length however, so should I just do this with PHP instead of MySQL or is there a way around this?

Comment: After changing 800 to 100 I still get the same error actually.

Comment: Did you remove the "id" column?

Comment: No, why would that affect it tho?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76560/discussion-between-kmgilbert100-and-chintan-parekh).

Comment: When you define a column with "increments", it is by default the primary key for the table..